# ASP.Net MVC3 Remote Data Annotation Not Working

Tags: data-annotations, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a class with data annotations using the Remote attribute:

```
public class Person 
{   
    [Remote("NameValidation","Validation", ErrorMessage = "Field is Invalid", Fields = "LastName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
}
```

In ValidationController:

```
    public ActionResult NameValidation(string FirstName, string LastName)
    {
        bool isNameValid = true;

        if (FirstName.Contains("John") && LastName.Contains("Doe"))
        {
            isNameValid = false;
        }

        return Json(isNameValid, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In the view I have:

```
@{Html.EnableClientValidation(); }
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.FirstName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.FirstName)
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.LastName) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.LastName)

   <input name="finishButton" type="submit" id="button" >
}
```

The NameValidation only gets called if I also add the Required attribute like this:

```
public class Person 
{   
    [Required]
    [Remote("NameValidation","Validation", ErrorMessage = "Field is Invalid", Fields = "LastName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 
}
```

How do I get the Remote validation to work without having to have the Required validation?

Answer (score 0):

Update to MVC3 RC2. I just tried it without the Required attribute. Its working.
One thing I found strange though, is that the remote validation is sometimes fired on every key press and onchange the other times